# Invalid syntax that I can't find an issue with

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry, quite a newbie at programming, but I can't seem to find the issue here. Python is saying that the issue is between the last bracket and the double quotation mark.

```
b = input("Tell me,", name", what can you see in front of you? ")
```

The issue is still present if I change the double quotation mark to a single, or change the text.

Comment: `name",` the comma is on the wrong side of the quote! Instead consider using a formatted string `input("Tell me, %s what can you see in front of you? " % name)`

Answer (score 2):

You need a comma after `name` and before `"`, to separate the variable from the string following it.

```
b = input("Tell me,", name", what can you see in front of you? ")   # ERROR
b = input("Tell me,", name, ", what can you see in front of you? ") # NO SYNTAX ERROR
```

However, note that `input()` takes a single argument rather than multiple arguments, so in order to do this you'd actually want to use `+` to concatenate the strings instead of passing multiple arguments. Trying to pass multiple arguments to `input()` would give you a `TypeError`.

As multiple other answers have pointed out, using string concatenation for `input()` can be a bit confusing, especially when you're trying to essentially concatenate parts of a string that's all one sentence. Using the string formatting operators beforehand can make for clearer code:

```
b = input("Tell me, {}, what can you see in front of you? ".format(name))
```

The string you pass to `format` will be inserted where the `{}` placeholder is in the format string.

Comment: Um... `TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3`

Comment: Check the value of `name`. It has to be a `str`. In your case it seems to be a `tuple` or `list`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a comma missing around `", name"`

But that won't work anyway because `input()` doesn't work like `print()`.

```
In [5]: b = input("Tell me,", name, ", what can you see in front of you? ")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3b47224115df> in <module>()
----> 1 b = input("Tell me,", name, ", what can you see in front of you? ")

TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

You could use string formatting. Would be clearer to see.

```
b = input("Tell me, {} what can you see in front of you?".format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

String format will make this much more readable and less error prone:

```
b = input("Tell me, {0}, what can you see in front of you? ".format(name))
```